# Appdomain refresh / restart

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a webservice and have the following observation:
Even if I simply add a text file to the directory (bin) where all the dlls referred by the webservice is stored, the appdomain refreshes.

This causes all the user sessions stored in a Dictionary (in one of the dlls) to be erased.

For example, if the dictionary above is contained in a dll, say, sessiondict.dll and I am replacing another dll that has no dependancy whatsoever with sessiondict.dll, then why should this data be lost?

Am I missing anything?

**EDIT:**

Though I am reading more on AppDomain restarts, however, have not been yet able to figure out as to why the design is such that even adding a text file in the bin folder causes the appdomain to restart.

Comment: Load the Session dll in a separate AppDomain at application start using static `AppDomain.CreateDomain()` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47e8e141.aspx and at this blog post: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jan/19/Assembly-Loading-across-AppDomains

Comment: I would specifically like to know why this behavior is seen. Should't Microsoft had taken care to only compile those dependencies that have changed. Why uploading a text file in the bin folder should cause an appdomain refresh/restart?

Comment: This article should help you understand some of it: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/add-stability-to-your-aspnet-applications-with-appdomains/429

Comment: @CSharpVJ The article is a good read to understand AppDomain and so are so many articles cited in StackOverflow. Hoever, none answer my question :|

Comment: @AakashRoy - Look at it from the other side - why should anyone be uploading text files to the bin folder?  The bin folder should contain the binaries for an application, not data files.  There are plenty of other locations to store your data.  .NET doesn't support replacement of one DLL while a program is running, and the bin directory is for a single application, so there's no valid reason I'm aware of for monitoring only the files connected with the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard behaviour - any time anything in the bin directory is touched (as well as other locations such as web.config) then your appdomain will recycle.

You shouldn't be storing data inside the bin directory.  You also should be aware that IIS by default will recycle the appdomain at regular intervals unless you've told it not to (once per day by default I believe).

As you can't replace one part of an application anyway, I'm not sure what the valid reasons for doing this are?

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx) is a good explanation of what can cause AppDomain recycles.

Comment: If you need to modify the default recycling behaviour for some reason, this blog post should be useful: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/02/21/ASP.NET-v2.0-_2D00_-AppDomain-recycles_2C00_-more-common-than-before.aspx. EDIT: Sorry, the link is broken in this comment - you may need to check the guy's blog manually.

Comment: Accepting @Richard's answer. He pointed out well what the other side of the coin reads. The assemblies that define a web service is the bin directory. May be simple enough to understand, but I took time to understand this since I wanted know what could be the implications otherwise. For example, then the worker process would have keep track of all changes occurring in the bin directory. This would have a risk of having to resolve undefined references to addresses in the call stack frames. May be this is also the reason that an assembly cannot be unloaded dynamically from a process.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary` is stored in local variable that lives in memory inside App domain.
When content is updated in bin folder AppDomain is recycled. Recycling means that .NET unloads existing AppDomain (erase memory used by all local varriables stored in all loaded classes) and constructs new AppDomain and initiates new classes (that probably will create an empty `Dictionary` in your code).

It doesn't matter if DLL changed or not. Instance of `Class` is destroyed because ASP.NET thinks that any change in bin folder affects configuration and site should be restarted with new configuration.

To solve the issue you may:

1. Store critical Session variables in persistent storage (prefferable)
2. Do not update content of BIN folder.